# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngx-places"

Tags: angular

I have installed `ngx-google-places-autocomplete` module. After setting i got this error.

> core.js:14597 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template
>   parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to
>   "ngx-places" ("]#placesRef="ngx-places"
>   (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)" />

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. In the directive source code, it is defined as 'exportAs' property. https://github.com/skynet2/ngx-google-places-autocomplete/blob/master/src/ngx-google-places-autocomplete.directive.ts

created stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6us2at?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html . It works, might be issue related to npm module not installed successfully. You can try removing 'node_modules' and run 'npm install' again.